# Laravel same view with different Options depending on the way to get there

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel Web-Application and a view in it that shows all the cars from the database. (It's a booking system for cars)

Now I want to have a button in that view, that allows a user to add and delete cars , but I only want this button to appear when the view is accessed over a certain button. When the view is accessed in any other way (other button or typing the link manually,) the button (to add/delete cars) should not be seen.

How can I realize that in a nice and clean way?

Best regards,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put those buttons in if conditions

Here I used $show_button variable just for an example

You can use your conditional data as per your requirements

In controller:

Here I used my_index.blade.php just for an example

```
public function index(){
   $show_button == 1; //set value as per your requirement

   return view('my_index', compact('show_button'));
}
```

In blade file:

```
@if($show_button == 1)
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Button-1</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Button-2</button>
@endif
```

**OR**

If you want to display those buttons on click of another button then use jquery or javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<div id="action_div" style="display:none;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</div>

<button class="other_button">show action buttons</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.other_button').on('click', function(){
            $(document).find('#action_div').show();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: i like the blade templating solution, but where do i set the show_button variable? how does the Controller know, which button i used to call the index function, for example?